# Refactor code without cursor PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can I refactor these lines of code without using `CURSOR`?
I am beginner in PL/SQL.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c_emps IS
    SELECT employee_id
      FROM bonus;

  v_region HR.REGIONS.region_name%TYPE;
  v_salary hr.employees.salary%TYPE;

BEGIN
  FOR r_emps IN c_emps LOOP
    SELECT reg.region_name, emp.salary
      INTO v_region, v_salary
      FROM hr.employees   emp,
           hr.departments dep,
           hr.Locations   loc,
           hr.countries   cot,
           hr.regions     reg
     WHERE emp.department_id = dep.department_id AND
           dep.location_id = loc.location_id AND
           loc.country_id = cot.country_id AND
           cot.region_id = reg.region_id AND
           employee_id = r_emps.employee_id;

    IF v_region = 'Europe' THEN
      UPDATE bonus
         SET bonus = bonus + (v_salary * .01)
       WHERE employee_id = r_emps.employee_id;
    ELSE
      UPDATE bonus
         SET bonus = v_salary * .01
       WHERE employee_id = r_emps.employee_id;
    END IF;  
  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: Removing a cursor and just using relational logic is a good practice +1

Comment: You can do this in one update statement using a case statement. No need for the procedural, row-by-row approach you've taken. Why don't you try writing the update statement, and if you get stuck, edit your question with what you've managed to achieve, and we'll help you further.

Comment: p.s. you might find it useful to read [this](http://www.orchestrapit.co.uk/?p=171)

Comment: I completely agree with @Boneist If you could do it in SQL, don't use PL/SQL. `PL/SQL --> LOOPS --> Row-by-row a.k.a slow-by-slow`

Comment: @Boneist I must do it in PL/SQL. Anyway, thank you for your comment.

Comment: @LalitKumarB I must use PL/SQL

Comment: Then if performance doesn't matter to you, no need to declare the cursor, simply use the cursor for loop as I have shown in the answer. Else, for better performance, use FORALL with BULK COLLECT.

Comment: you can do sql in PL/SQL... `begin update ....; end;`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> CURSOR c_emps IS
>     SELECT employee_id
>       FROM bonus;
> ```

You don't need to explicitly declare the CURSOR. You could do it in the **CURSOR FOR LOOP** itself:

```
FOR r_emps IN (SELECT employee_id FROM bonus) 
LOOP
```

If **PL/SQL** is not mandatory, then you could do it in plain **SQL** using **CASE expression** in the **UPDATE** statement.

Something like,

```
UPDATE bonus
SET bonus =
  CASE
    WHEN region = 'Europe'
    THEN bonus    + (v_salary * .01)
    ELSE v_salary * .01
...
and so on
```

Yes, you need to rewrite the entire PL/SQL code into a SQL update statement. But, it would be much better and faster. For loop is *row-by-row* processing, thus it is *slow-by-slow*. Avoid PL/SQL if you could do the same in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

When working with SQL Server, an awful lot of effort is taken to avoid cursors because they are handled very poorly. Using a cursor in SQL Server is like slogging waist-deep through molasses. Oracle handles cursors much better so you see a lot more row-by-row work in Oracle. Too much, really. Even in Oracle, if something can be done with a single SQL statement, it is far superior than using PL/SQL cursors and looping.

Unfortunately, Oracle doesn't allow joins in `UPDATE` statements. But not to worry, the more recent innovation, the `MERGE` statement does.

```
MERGE INTO BONUS B
USING(
    SELECT  EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID, EMP.SALARY, REG.REGION_NAME
    FROM    HR.EMPLOYEES   EMP
    JOIN    HR.DEPARTMENTS DEP
       ON   DEP.DEPARTMENT_ID = EMP.DEPARTMENT_ID
    JOIN    HR.LOCATIONS   LOC
       ON   LOC.LOCATION_ID = DEP.LOCATION_ID
    JOIN    HR.COUNTRIES   COT
       ON   COT.COUNTRY_ID = LOC.COUNTRY_ID
    JOIN    HR.REGIONS     REG
       ON   REG.REGION_ID = COT.REGION_ID ) U
ON( U.EMPLOYEE_ID = b.EMPLOYEE_ID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET B.BONUS =( u.SALARY * 0.01 ) +
        CASE U.REGION_NAME WHEN 'Europe' THEN B.BONUS ELSE 0 END;
```

How nice that the `when not matched` clause is not required, effectively turning the `merge` into a very flexible `update`.